About \longfbox package
Can you guys help me how to make a frame that look like this (it would be even better if you know how to make colors like those in the picture). I have always used \tcolorbox but they look like rectangles, which are a little ugly. While with \longfbox package, there have always been errors with this package when I try to insert ít. Can you also help me fix this bug? I will appreciate your help. 

Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a document example (MWE: Minimal Working Example)  with use of tcolorbox. So far my experiences shows, that boxes created by tcolorbox always looks nice ...

"look like rectanges"???  If you go texdoc tcolorbox the very first page before you even read any words has boxes with rounded corners see tcolorbox manual cover

There is a problem for many years with longfbox which you can solve with this addition to preamble:
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\@tempdimd\else\newdimen\@tempdimd\fi
\makeatother

Here is now an example from the documentation I had to use FloralWhite and not floralwhite.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{longfbox}
\makeatletter
\ifdefined\@tempdimd\else\newdimen\@tempdimd\fi
\makeatother

\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor}
\begin{document}
\begin{longfbox}[
  margin-right=6em,
  padding=1.5em,
  background-color=FloralWhite,
  background-clip=padding-box,
  border-width=2pt,
  border-radius=15pt,
  border-top-left-radius=30pt,
  border-left-width=8pt,
  border-left-color=teal,
  border-right-style=double,
]
 A longfbox with rounded corners.
\end{longfbox}
\end{document}


As per your question about a "titled" longfbox, I don't know not having practiced the package nor read its doc fully.
